# Tastypie, field from an attribute or function?

Tags: django, tastypie

For instance, I'd like to add `absolute_url` field when I return my model's json data.

I added the following to my model

```
@property
def absolute_url(self):
    return self.get_absolute_url()
```

then in my tastypie resource

```
absolute_url = fields.CharField(attribute="absolute_url", readonly=True)

class Meta:
    fields = [... 'absolute_url' .. ]
```

But this was not enough to make my resource to include the `absolute_url` data in the JSON response.

I had to use `dehydrate` to include the field.

The doc isn't clear about the effect of defining a field (here absolute_url CharField).

Comment: I'm not sure you actually need to add 'absolute_url' inside the fields list. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong here, which is strange because I've got numerous fields declared the exact same way as yours (and working)... Have you tried without the property decorator ?

Comment: Thanks. Strange, I removed the @property but no.. removed 'absolute_url' from fields and still no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out 'absolute_url' is rather special field in tastypie, and there's an even option for it.

[include_absolute_url](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#include-absolute-url)